# How to make Fastapi containerization with Postgresql database

Tags: docker-compose, fastapi

**When i run this command 'docker-compose up --build' for Fastapi application, I get this error:**

```
cwms_backend | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
cwms_backend | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
cwms_backend | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using WatchFiles
cwms_backend | Process SpawnProcess-1:
cwms_backend | Traceback (most recent call last):
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
cwms_backend |     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3303, in raw_connection
cwms_backend |     return self.pool.connect()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 449, in connect
cwms_backend |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
cwms_backend |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 712, in checkout
cwms_backend |     rec = pool._do_get()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 180, in _do_get
cwms_backend |     self._dec_overflow()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
cwms_backend |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
cwms_backend |     return self._create_connection()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
cwms_backend |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 674, in __init__
cwms_backend |     self.__connect()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 901, in __connect
cwms_backend |     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
cwms_backend |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 896, in __connect
cwms_backend |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 643, in connect
cwms_backend |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
cwms_backend |     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
cwms_backend |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
cwms_backend | psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
cwms_backend |  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
cwms_backend | connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
cwms_backend |  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
cwms_backend | 
cwms_backend | 
cwms_backend | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
cwms_backend | 
cwms_backend | Traceback (most recent call last):
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
cwms_backend |     self.run()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
cwms_backend |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
cwms_backend |     target(sockets=sockets)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
cwms_backend |     return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
cwms_backend |     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
cwms_backend |   File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
cwms_backend |     config.load()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 477, in load
cwms_backend |     self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
cwms_backend |     module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
cwms_backend |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
cwms_backend |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
cwms_backend |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
cwms_backend |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
cwms_backend |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
cwms_backend |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
cwms_backend |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
cwms_backend |   File "/app/./main.py", line 11, in <module>
cwms_backend |     models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 5825, in create_all
cwms_backend |     bind._run_ddl_visitor(
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3253, in _run_ddl_visitor
cwms_backend |     with self.begin() as conn:
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
cwms_backend |     return next(self.gen)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3243, in begin
cwms_backend |     with self.connect() as conn:
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3279, in connect
cwms_backend |     return self._connection_cls(self)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
cwms_backend |     Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2443, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
cwms_backend |     raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
cwms_backend |     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3303, in raw_connection
cwms_backend |     return self.pool.connect()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 449, in connect
cwms_backend |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
cwms_backend |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 712, in checkout
cwms_backend |     rec = pool._do_get()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 180, in _do_get
cwms_backend |     self._dec_overflow()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
cwms_backend |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
cwms_backend |     return self._create_connection()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
cwms_backend |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 674, in __init__
cwms_backend |     self.__connect()
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 901, in __connect
cwms_backend |     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
cwms_backend |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 896, in __connect
cwms_backend |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 643, in connect
cwms_backend |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
cwms_backend |     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
cwms_backend |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
cwms_backend |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
cwms_backend | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
cwms_backend |  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
cwms_backend | connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
cwms_backend |  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
cwms_backend | 
cwms_backend | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

**how can I solve this error ?, i just tried little bit but error still complaining especially connecting to the database Postgresql.**

**And these are contents of my docker-compose.yml file,
Please anyone can try to help me**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.2
    container_name: cwms_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Developer#1234
      - POSTGRES_DB=cwms
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build: .
    container_name: cwms_backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8002:8002"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: uvicorn main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://root:Developer#1234@localhost/cwms

networks:
  default:
    name: cwms
```